# How do I align drawable left horizontally in a perfect line with hint and stick them both closer to the bottom in a TextInputEditText?

Tags: android, css, xml, android-layout, material-ui

I need to set drawableLeft aligned horizontally with the hint and moved them both closer to the bottom of the TextInputEditText. I have tried a lot of attributes but to no avail! Could I be missing something here? 
Drawable seems to be where I want it but I need the hint to come below to align with drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_login_dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello!"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/teal_700"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_email_user_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_login_dialog_title">
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/ti_et_email_user_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_email_24"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="@string/field_hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_email_user_id">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/ti_et_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_24"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="@string/field_hint_password" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Layout resource file in Android Studio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Remove

```
android:drawableLeft="Drawable"
```

from TextInputEditText and add

```
app:startIconDrawable="Drawable"
```

into the TextInputLayout

or you can replace your TextInputLayout from below code

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_email_user_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/share_card"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/icn_sort_by"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_login_dialog_title">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/ti_et_email_user_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make your drawable height and weight 24dp. Then add these to your TextInputEditText. This is not an official answer btw. I do it like this every time.

```
android:paddingVertical="10dp"
android:drawablePadding="10dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

Comment: it will change when the screen size is large.

Comment: It is not proper soution edit text hint and inputed text will be combine if you try check my answer if you want proper solution

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, Monjur, but the first answer by @Bhojaviya Sagar is closer to what I am looking for.